# Flow type issue with string.match()

Tags: javascript, flowtype

There's a script in my program that eventually calls a function that accepts a string and runs `.match(regex)` on that string.

**As per MDN:**
`String.prototype.match(regex)` returns an `array` data type of which I only need to access the first index `[0]`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

In every way I've tried to re-organize this script I get the flow error:

> "Cannot get `findStationId(...)[0]` because an index signature declaring the expected key / value type is missing in null [1]."

The Organization of the function isn't where I'm having trouble, but with the `[0]` index reference.

**How can I correctly type check this and declare the expected values?**

```
// @flow

type RssResults = Array<{
  title: string,
  contentSnippet: string
}>

const findStationId = (string: string): Array<any> | null => string.match(/([0-9]{5}|[A-Z\d]{5})/)

export default (rssResults: RssResults) => {
  const entries = []
  rssResults.forEach((entry) => {
    const observation = {}
    observation.title = entry.title
    const id = findStationId(entry.title)[0] // flow errors here on [0]
    observation.id = id.toLowerCase()

    // ...        

    entries.push(observation)
  })
return entries
}
```

.flowconfig

```
[ignore]
.*/test/*

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.jsx
module.file_ext=.json
module.file_ext=.css
module.file_ext=.scss
module.name_mapper.extension='css' -> 'empty/object'
module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> 'empty/object'

[strict]

[untyped]
.*/node_modules/**/.*
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer at that MDN page, it states:

> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.

with "null if no matches are found." being the critical part here. `null[0]` does not make sense. Your own return type `Array<any> | null` also mentions this.

So either your

```
const id = findStationId(entry.title)[0]
```

should do

```
const match = findStationId(entry.title)
if (!match) throw new Error("No station ID found")
const id = match[0]
```

or you should change `findStationId` to not allow a `null` return.

```
const findStationId = (string: string): Array<any> => {
  const match = string.match(/([0-9]{5}|[A-Z\d]{5})/)
  if (!match) throw new Error("No station ID found")
  return match
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, makes sense to me now!